# Launch4j - java-executable wrapper -- Windows7

Tags: java, windows-7, launch4j

Scenario:
java-app wrapped with launch4j -- works fine on the dev-machine with Windows Vista  -- on a plain Windows7 machine it asks to install Java JRE - but wont start the application.

Anybody managed to create an executable using a java-wrapper for Windows7.

Background: 
- jar has all dependend jars and resources
- tried with a custom manifest as well as a build in manifest pointing to the Main class

Thanks for anykind of help

Comment: When you say "won't start the application", do you have any errors ? If so, please include them in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - and sorry - I think - I figured out what went wrong. - After checking the 23bit/64bit forum entry - I realised I had weird - jvm-options setting.

Answer (score 1):

launch4j is not a JRE. It neither converts Java's object into a executable binary format to be run in Windows.

It explains it pretty well: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I use NSIS instead of launch4j to launch my java apps:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Java_Launcher_with_automatic_JRE_installation